# How to disable all controls in custom bottom sheet during the future delayed only

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a bottom sheet as the below figure:

[image: bottom sheet]

the problem now when click any controls twice for example click on toggle buttons tase twice or switching between tabs in sort part fast it shows a black screen as the below:

[image: black screen]

and I found this error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: A DashboardService was used after being disposed.
Once you have called dispose() on a DashboardService, it can no longer be used.
```

and this is the below related code part widget:

```
import 'package:BOTS/globals/localize.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:BOTS/widgets/forms/heightSpacer.dart';
import 'package:BOTS/widgets/label.dart';
import 'package:BOTS/widgets/revenyouDivider.dart';

import '../../backend/backend.dart';
import '../../globals/constants.dart';
import 'package:BOTS/pages/dashboard/dashboardService.dart';

class DashboardOptionsBottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  final DashboardService dashboardService;
  // final bool open;
  const DashboardOptionsBottomSheet({
    Key key,
    this.dashboardService,
    // this.open,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  DashboardOptionsBottomSheetState createState() =>
      DashboardOptionsBottomSheetState(dashboardService);
}

class DashboardOptionsBottomSheetState
    extends State<DashboardOptionsBottomSheet> {
  final DashboardService dashboardService;
  // bool open;

  DashboardOptionsBottomSheetState(this.dashboardService);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final _segmentWidth = (_width - 50.0) / 3;

    String results = Localize.of(context).trans("dashboardOptions.results");
    String newest = Localize.of(context).trans("dashboardOptions.newest");
    String amount = Localize.of(context).trans("dashboardOptions.amount");
    var sharedValue = 0;
    final bold = FontWeight.w700;
    final med = FontWeight.w500;
    FontWeight _resultsWeight = med;
    FontWeight _newestWeight = med;
    FontWeight _amountWeight = med;

    Map<int, Widget> segmentMap() {
      return <int, Widget>{
        0: Container(
          height: 37,
          width: _segmentWidth,
          child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Label(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  text: results,
                  size: 14,
                  fontWeight: _resultsWeight,
                ),
              ]),
        ),
        1: Container(
          height: 37,
          width: _segmentWidth,
          child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Label(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  text: newest,
                  size: 14,
                  fontWeight: _newestWeight,
                ),
              ]),
        ),
        2: Container(
          height: 37,
          width: _segmentWidth,
          child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Label(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  text: amount,
                  size: 14,
                  fontWeight: _amountWeight,
                ),
              ]),
        ),
      };
    }

    SortedBy sortedBy = dashboardService.sortedBy;
    switch (sortedBy) {
      case SortedBy.results:
        sharedValue = 0;
        _resultsWeight = bold;
        _newestWeight = med;
        _amountWeight = med;
        break;
      case SortedBy.newest:
        sharedValue = 1;
        _resultsWeight = med;
        _newestWeight = bold;
        _amountWeight = med;
        break;
      case SortedBy.amount:
        sharedValue = 2;
        _resultsWeight = med;
        _newestWeight = med;
        _amountWeight = bold;
        break;
    }
    String _sorted;

    return Material(
      child: Container(
        height: 380,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(contrastColor3),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            HeightSpacer(height: 30),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
                  child: TitleLabel(
                    text: Localize.of(context).trans("dashboardOptions.sortBy"),
                    size: 16,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            HeightSpacer(height: 20),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, right: 25.0),
              child: Container(
                child: CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl(
                  children: segmentMap(),
                  onValueChanged: (int val) {
                    sharedValue = val;
                    SortedBy sortedBy;
                    switch (val) {
                      case 0:
                        sortedBy = SortedBy.results;
                        _sorted = "results";

                        _newestWeight = med;
                        _amountWeight = med;
                        break;
                      case 1:
                        sortedBy = SortedBy.newest;
                        _sorted = "newest";
                        _resultsWeight = med;

                        _amountWeight = med;
                        break;
                      case 2:
                        sortedBy = SortedBy.amount;
                        _sorted = "amount";
                        _resultsWeight = med;
                        _newestWeight = med;

                        break;
                    }
                    dashboardService.clearStrategies();

                    dashboardService.sortedBy = sortedBy;
                    prefs.sortedBy = _sorted;
                    dashboardService
                        .getBalanceData(dashboardService.showCrypto);
                    dashboardService.fetchAllStrategies();
                    setState(() {});
                      Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300), () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      });
                  },
                  groupValue: sharedValue,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            HeightSpacer(height: 20),
            RevenYouDivider(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
            ),
            HeightSpacer(height: 30),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
                  child: TitleLabel(
                    text:
                        Localize.of(context).trans("dashboardOptions.display"),
                    size: 16,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            HeightSpacer(height: 12),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
                  child: Label(
                    text: Localize.of(context)
                        .trans("dashboardOptions.showGraphs"),
                    size: 14,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                  child: Switch(
                    value: dashboardService.showGraphs,
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      dashboardService.clearStrategies();
                      dashboardService.showGraphs = val;
                      prefs.showGraphs = val;
                      dashboardService
                          .getBalanceData(dashboardService.showCrypto);
                      dashboardService.fetchAllStrategies();

                      // Update the switch UI, then pop the bottomsheet after a delay
                      setState(() {});
                        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300), () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        });
                    },
                    activeColor: Colors.white,
                    activeTrackColor: Color(primaryColor5),
                    inactiveTrackColor: Color(contrastColor2),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            HeightSpacer(height: 12),
            RevenYouDivider(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
            ),
            HeightSpacer(height: 12),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
                  child: Label(
                    text: Localize.of(context)
                        .trans("dashboardOptions.showCrypto"),
                    size: 14,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                  child: Switch(
                    value: dashboardService.showCrypto,
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      dashboardService.clearStrategies();
                      dashboardService.showCrypto = val;
                      prefs.showCrypto = val;
                      dashboardService.getBalanceData(val);
                      dashboardService.fetchAllStrategies();

                      // Update the switch UI, then pop the bottomsheet after a delay
                      setState(() {});
                        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300), () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        });
                    },
                    activeColor: Colors.white,
                    activeTrackColor: Color(primaryColor5),
                    activeThumbImage: AssetImage(
                      "assets/artwork/crypto/crypto.webp",
                    ),
                    inactiveThumbImage: AssetImage(
                      "assets/artwork/euro/euro.webp",
                    ),
                    inactiveTrackColor: Color(contrastColor2),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            HeightSpacer(height: 12),
            RevenYouDivider(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
            ),
            Container(height: 20),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the part dashboard.dart which is returns the bottom sheet:

```
return DashboardOptionsBottomSheet(
                                                    dashboardService: service,
                                                  );
```

what I need now I want to disable any button or any control in the bottom sheet after click any item during the future delay only and make them enable again after the bottom sheet disappears.

I tried to find widget the disable other widget `AbsorbPointer()` but I don't know how to put this widget in a condition to handle this...

Any suggestions for how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

wrap the widget with AbsorbPointer widget

```
 AbsorbPointer(
        absorbing: _absorbing,
        child: CustomWidget(),
      )
```

The simple way is create StreamController wrap your widget with StreamBuilder
and pass boolean value whether to enable or disable Absorbing.